# I want to run this code without creating instance of class(object). Is it possible? why not?

Tags: java, multithreading, object, constructor, static

```
public class Constructor_benifit{
public static void main(String[] args){
    System.out.println("In primary Thread");
    A a=new A("Test string for secondary thread");
    Thread thread_object=new Thread(a);
    thread_object.start();
}
static class A implements Runnable
{
    String to_print;
    public A(String to_print){
        this.to_print=to_print;
    }
    public void run(){
        System.out.println(to_print);
    }

}}
```

---

i want to run this code without creating object...i made class A static to call it without object but, still don't know how to call it.
This code works fine. I just wanted to know if maybe any other method to execute this code in simple way?

Comment: What do you mean by "still not getting it right"? Are you getting an error: please add it to the question. If you are not getting the expected behaviour then please explain the behaviour you are getting *and* what you expected.

Comment: A is a static class, but it's members are instance members. so in order to use those, you'll need to instantiate A

Comment: @Stultuske how to instantiate class A? i dont understand

Comment: But A is a thead. So for initializing a thread you need to instantiate that. `A.run()` will call the `run()` method but it wont start the thread

Comment: @ParitoshBhatt you already instantiate it. 
    A a=new A("Test string for secondary thread"); -> this line creates an instance a of type A

Comment: @Richard i Edited my post. and yes this code works fine

Comment: Why you don't want to instantiate I cannot get that

Comment: @Stultuske i made class A static thinking that i can call it without creating its object. This code also works fine without static class A.

Comment: @ParitoshBhatt just because the class is static, doesn't mean that it's members are.

Comment: @Shantanu i just want to know if there is a way without it or not? for example we create object using new keyword without giving it name like (new A("message"))

Comment: How do you want to change the code? Currently you're doing `new A("...")`.  Do you want to get rid of this line? Or what kind of other change you would like to make?

Comment: @ParitoshBhatt For creating a thread you **must** intialise the class by calling a constructor. No other way behind that

Comment: Constructer is for initialising the object in memory. How on earth you can make it static

Comment: Static inner class means you don't need an instance of the container class (in your case Constructor_benifit) to construct your class.

Comment: @Sodala So, if i don't make instance of class then i cant pass it onto the Thread right? and i can still call that inner class directly via container class right?

Comment: @Dikla yes, i just want to get rid of that line i.e. object creation.

Comment: @ParitoshBhatt make a constructor static? That makes no sense at all. I would recommend you start by learning the basics before messing around with Threads.

Comment: @Stultuske ok, i got it about the constructor and object creation, i just wanted to make more sense out of this code.

Comment: @Paritosh Bhatt to be sure you understand me correctly: you need an instance of A but you don't need an instance of Constructor_benifit. This is why you put static before class A. If you remove static then it doesn t compile because you need to create an instance of Constructor_benifit before. And after that you also need an instance of A.

Comment: @Sodala in above code if i dont put static in class A still it is running. my question was more related to calling of class and its object creation at inner and outer level of class in a simple way. it is my mistake that i could not explain myself as i am still new to java and its naming conventions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you cannot start a Thread without creating an object.

By implementing Runnable you should override this method:

```
public void run(){
```

And this method has already been defined as virtual(non-static) in the Runnable interface.

If you want to create a thread without implementing the Runnable interface, then you should extend the Thread class. Which does not provide static methods for starting and running the thread. Again you will need to create an instance of the class A.

If you just need to avoid the extra object creation you could use this code.
Again we are creating object. But just one object instead of two.

```
public class Constructor_benifit{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println("In primary Thread");
        Thread thread_object=new A("Test string for secondary thread");
        thread_object.start();
    }
    static class A extends Thread
    {
        private String to_print;
        public A(String to_print){
            this.to_print=to_print;
        }
        public void run(){
            System.out.println(to_print);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: It's almost always not a good idea to extend `Thread`. Inheritance establishes an "is-a" relationship; the derived type "is-a" (its supertype). So unless your runnable "is-a" thread, it's best just to make it a `Runnable` and pass an instance to the vanilla `Thread` class.

Answer (score 0):

> I just wanted to know if maybe any other method to execute this code in simple way?

In case you just want to execute it in a simple way you can use [Lambda Expressions in Java 8](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html)

```
public class TestClass{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println("In primary Thread");
        String to_print = "Test string for secondary thread";
        Thread thread_object=new Thread(()->System.out.println(to_print));
        thread_object.start();
    }
}
```